# How to execute InitMap() inside settimeout ionic 4

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic4

I'm using ion-segement in my project, I'm using the google map but I got this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

here's the code :

```
@ViewChild('mapElement', { static: true }) mapNativeElement: ElementRef;
 initMap() {
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapNativeElement.nativeElement, {
  zoom: 4,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  center: { lat: 53.0000, lng: 9.0000 },
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
} 


segmentChanged(event){
   if(event.detail.value=== 'map'){
       setTimeout(() => 
         this.initMap()
   ,5000)

 }

}
```

html:

```
 <div *ngSwitchCase="'map'">
    <div  #mapElement class="map"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your full code so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?